# Change the value of a data attribute using Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change a data attribute of a div element base on the users screen resolution, i am using the impress.js library and i want to set the div overview that has a data attribute of `scale`, the value that i want to toggle is 2.0 for desktop and 2.5 for laptop.

So far below is my code.

```
<div id="overview" class="step" data-x="-700" data-y="-500" data-scale="2">
    </div>
```

My jquery code is.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

   if(window.innerWidth == 1680){

   $('#overview').data('scale', 2);

   }else{

     $('#overview').data('scale', 2.5);

   }

})
```

I am able to get the value of the innerWidth but cannot get to change the value of the data attribute, Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: You didn't say anything about problem...

Comment: If you want to change attribute use `.attr()` i.e. `$('#overview').attr('data-scale', 2.5);`

Comment: `window.innerWidth == 1680` need to be `window.innerWidth <= 1680`. because exactly match will not possible all time. And it need to be:- `$('#overview').attr('data-scale', 2.5);`  or `$('#overview').attr('data-scale', 2);`

Comment: use `if($(window).width() >= 1680){}` instead your condition

Comment: Sorry but you cannot change the value of the scale while impress is at work, impress.js has its own way of resetting the view port when the screen change, what you can to is disable the auto scaling by putting `data-min-scale="1" data-max-scale="1"` on your `<div id='impress'></div>` good try do.

Comment: @KaoriYui thanks that do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {

   if(window.innerWidth == 1680){

   $('#overview').attr('data-scale', '2');

   }else{

     $('#overview').attr('data-scale', '2.5');

   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overview" class="step" data-x="-700" data-y="-500" data-scale="2">demo
</div>
```

Hope this may helps you.